# How to play audio/video using AirPlay in cocoa app

Tags: macos, cocoa, avplayer, airplay, qtkit

I am working on a **cocoa app** where i play some audio and video using url. I have used **QTMovieview** for playing **Audio/Video**.
Now **what is my requirement is to play audio/video on another device like AppleTv/Another Mac by using airplay functionality.**

I had search, but nothing found to implement airplay in cocoa application.
In IOS AVPlayer have functionality to play Audio/Video using airplay. But in OSX i didn't found anything.

Can anyone help to implement this.
Or any link which help me to implement airplay functionality using QTMovie or any other way.

Thanks in advance for help.